# How to edit templated item in WPF combobox without triggering drop-down

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox, selecteditem

I am trying to create a ComboBox that contains a list of date range selection options.  The thought is that the user will first choose a date range selection option, and then edit the appropriate fields as they are displayed in the ComboBox selected item field.  Unfortunately, attempting to edit the editable fields on the selected item retriggers the ComboBox drop-down, so it is impossible to actually change any values.  Is there a way to allow the user to click in the selected item textbox fields without triggering the ComboBox drop-down?

The template for the date range selector is:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:DateRangeSelectionViewModel}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Date range:" Margin="15,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,5,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

... and below is an example date range selector.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:LastNDaysViewModel}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="Last" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding DayCount, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsHitTestVisible="True"
                            BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{Binding HasErrors, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource BoolToBrushConverter}}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,0,5,0" Text="days" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

In case it matters, I am using MVVM and MahApps.

Comment: Not gonna work that way. However, it should be trivial to *overlay* another control on top of the "item area" of the combo, which displays the combobox's selected item any way you like, editable or not. Leave the combo down-arrow button area exposed for the user to click on.

Comment: Just an opinion, and being [not a big fan](http://www.fuckdropdowns.com/) of drop downs, would a range slider maybe offer a little better UX in this instance?

Comment: I ended up going with a drop-down allowing the user to select how to specify the date range, and then use a content presenter to display the date range config view - not as compact as I would have liked, but oh well.  Range slider is an interesting idea; I might try that if I come to hate comboboxes more.  (I seem to be getting there fast.)